# annotation_custom is not placing the grobs

Tags: r, ggplot2, insets

Here is a code I have written:

```
sp9 <- ggplot(PWPdf3_12_1250, aes(log10(Avsize), log10(Prob))) +
  geom_point(color= "blue")

plotx <- ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(color= "blue")

#plot example from internet
plotx + 
  annotation_custom(
    ggplotGrob(sp9), 
    xmin = 5, xmax = 7, ymin = 30, ymax = 44
  )

#plotting my own data
sp9+ 
  annotation_custom(
    ggplotGrob(sp9), 
    xmin = 5, xmax = 7, ymin = 30, ymax = 44
  )
```

The outputs are :

[image]

[image]

I do not know why annotation_custom successfully insets the grob in case 1 , but fails to do so in case 2.
I have included libraries egg and tidyverse

Comment: your x and y axis are different than the example data so you need different xmin,ymin,etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot, much appreciated